# Loading a .csv from a non-mapped network drive (python)

Tags: python, jupyter

[picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDoKU.png)

Above is my attempt to load a .csv from a network drive at my company. For a variety of reasons, I do not wish to map the drive, and would like to load it as is. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you having any error? you can move the file to local computer and try it again

Answer (score 1):

try:

`df = pd.read_csv('\\\\your\\network\\unmapped\\drive\\file.csv')`

or:

`df = pd.read_csv(r'\\your\network\unmapped\drive\file.csv')`

`\` is escape character in python. So you if you want to use it as character you should escape it or keep string as is with 'r'

Cheers